# Run Symfony2 Command in Background and poll the output via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, process, command

with the process component of SF2, it is possible to start asynchronous background tasks from a controller.

What I want to do now, is to write a javascript, that periodically checks for this command and fetches the output of that task, to keep the user informed of what is happening.

Is there a way to store the process and fetch information over several requests, so that I can poll it via an ajax request?

Comment: i think you'd be better off having the command push its progress updates to somewhere and then have your ajax call compare against that.

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. The problems I've come across are once you start your ajax call that process is waiting for a response, but you can't return a response from your command because that will terminate your script. Either your command will have to push its progress somewhere (not sure where) as @DerickF said or your command will have to call some other background process that still has to push updates somewhere. Give these two scenarios I think the easiest would be to find somewhere to push those updates in your original command.

Comment: Further to my first comment if you're pushing updates to the database you end up with a performance hit because instead of persisting everything with a large transaction you ending persisting with smaller transactions and your script will run longer. So some of the main things to figure out is where do you push those updates and how do you poll them?